# HTTP1.1 to HTTP/2: what about headers?

Tags: http, http2

In HTTP 1.1, the status line was

```
scheme/version code reason
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I see :scheme and :status headers in the HPACK spec. I don't however see anything for version or reason? Is there not one?

In a request in HTTP 1.1, the request line was

```
method uri scheme/version
POST http://myhost.com HTTP/1.1
```

I see :method and I see :path, which I think is just a relative path, which is not the same as the full absolute path (and since Chrome and Firefox are pushing HTTPS for HTTP/2, this may make sense). I do not see version header though.

Is there a version header? Or is it seen that this will always be known before the protocol decision such that it is not really needed?

What about reason codes? Is it assumed these are pretty constant so that goes away (I am guessing here)?

Comment: According to the [HTTP/2 RFC](http://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#discover-http): "A client that makes a request for an "http" URI __without prior knowledge__ about support for HTTP/2 on the next hop uses the HTTP Upgrade mechanism". I assume that if the client already knows that the server supports HTTP/2 it may use version `HTTP/2.0` initially. Also [Listing 9](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2916548/java-web-development/http-2-for-java-developers.html?page=2) on this introduction guide on HTTP2 has the version set to `HTTP/2.0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In HTTP/1, the version token was needed to differentiate HTTP/1.0 from HTTP/1.1, since they had the same wire representation, but were supporting different features.

For example, a client declaring HTTP/1.1 implicitly tells the server that it supports persistent connections and content  chunking.

With HTTP/2, the protocol version is *negotiated*.

In clear-text HTTP/2, the `Upgrade` header reports `h2c`, where the `2` means version 2 of the protocol. I imagine that for HTTP/3 the token will change to `h3c`. 
Similarly happens for encrypted HTTP/2 where the token `h2` is negotiated via ALPN.

Reason messages have been dropped as being redundant, as the status code was already conveying all the necessary information (not to mention that they could be attack vectors).

For these reasons, HTTP/2 does not have neither version nor reason pseudo-headers.