# Does HTTP/2.0 really work with HttpClient on Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, http2

As i heard you can use the `Version` property of `HttpClient` to target the final version of HTTP.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{

    var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, @"https://google.com") { Version = new Version(2,0) };
    var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(message);
    // ...
}
```

But when i look at the source code in CoreFX it confuses me a lot - it doesn't seem to be working with the last version of HTTP. At least i couldn't find anything usefull that targets 2.0

```
string httpVersion = null;
if (state.RequestMessage.Version == HttpVersionInternal.Version10)
{
    httpVersion = "HTTP/1.0";
}
else if (state.RequestMessage.Version == HttpVersionInternal.Version11)
{
    httpVersion = "HTTP/1.1";
}

// ...

// Create an HTTP request handle.
state.RequestHandle = Interop.WinHttp.WinHttpOpenRequest(
    connectHandle,
    state.RequestMessage.Method.Method,
    state.RequestMessage.RequestUri.PathAndQuery,
    httpVersion,
    Interop.WinHttp.WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
    Interop.WinHttp.WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
    flags);

// WILL USE HTTP/1.1 by default
[DllImport(Interop.Libraries.WinHttp, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern SafeWinHttpHandle WinHttpOpenRequest(
    SafeWinHttpHandle connectHandle,
    string verb,
    string objectName,
    string version,
    string referrer,
    string acceptTypes,
    uint flags);
```

Am i looking at something completely unrelated to the issue?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37373039/4137916), HTTP/2 doesn't have version headers, so you're looking in the wrong place. The switch to HTTP/2 is done through an `Upgrade` header.

Comment: @JeroenMostert can you write that as an answer?