# Why does HTTP/2 show a different type of header for status codes like 404

Tags: apache, http, http2, status, http-1.1

Why does HTTP/2 show a different type of header for status codes like 404 e.g:

When I curl a HTTP/2 compatible webserver for a file that doesn't exist, I get

```
HTTP/2 404
.....other headers
```

When I curl a HTTP/1.1 webserver for a file that doesn't exist, I get

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
.....Other headers
```

My question is, why does HTTP/2 remove/avoid the text "Not Found" for a 404?

My question is not about the version.

Thanks.

Comment: I just want an explination.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [http1.1 to http/2 what about version header and other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368350/http1-1-to-http-2-what-about-version-header-and-other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason phrase in the HTTP/2 protocol.

Comment: How would more answers be useful?

Comment: Yes. But then it was a simple question with a really simple answer.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368350/http1-1-to-http-2-what-about-version-header-and-other).